# Вывести bool[] из пользовательской функции c#

Tags: c#, функции

Не получается вывести из пользовательской функции массив `bool`. Функция должна сдвигать на 1 разряд влево значение входного массива, код рабочий. Решил сделать отдельную функцию, и не получается/не знаю как получить назад уже сдвинутый на 1 влево массив.

```
public bool[] sdvig(bool[] arr)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length-1; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = arr[i + 1];
    }
    arr[8] = false;
    return arr;
}
```

и подскажите как правильно вызвать функцию

```
array1 = sdvig(array);
```

Буду рад любой помощи.

UPD. Для проверки работоспособности заполняю таблицу
начальный массив 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1

```
bool[] arm = sdvig(element_golua);

for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.RowCount; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView1.ColumnCount; j++)
    {
        dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value = Convert.ToInt16(arm[j]);
    }
}
```

А на выходе только `0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1` во всех строках.

Comment: Что значит не получается ? Какую ошибку выдает ? Код рабочий и да вы верно вызываете метод.

Comment: @creamsun на входе у меня массив со значениями {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1} и на выходе такой же. Может я не правильно делаю другие шаги.

bool[] arm = sdvig(element_golua);
           

            for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.RowCount; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView1.ColumnCount; j++)
                {
                    dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value = Convert.ToInt16(arm[j]);
                }
            }

Comment: А что Вы на выходе хотите получить ? Напишите, какая ошибка всплывает ?

Comment: @creamsun обновил сам пост, добавил код

Comment: а какова длина массива? почему устанавливается жестко `arr[8] = false;`?

Comment: @creamsun длина массива 9(мне потом нужно будет делась суму по модулю с 9 разрядным полиномом) устанавливается жестко, потому что при сдвиге на 1 влево массива 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 на выходе я получу 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1, а не  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0. Если вы знаете другой способ сдвинуть массив bool[] , я с радостью его прочитаю.

Answer (score 1):

Разобрался сам, нужно было команду вызова функции записать в момент перехода на другую строку.

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.RowCount; i++)
{
    bool[] arm = sdvig(element_golua);
    for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView1.ColumnCount; j++)
    {
        dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value = Convert.ToInt16(arm[j]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Проблема в том, что вы смешиваете функциональный подход и императивный. Вам нужно определиться - вы либо изменяете старый массив, либо возвращаете новый.

Answer (score -1):

Коллега, вам бы стоило определиться, какого рода сдвиг вы хотите сделать. Если циклический, то вам нужно последний элемент массива заменить первым в итоге. Если же простой, то тогда определитесь, каким значением должен будет проинициализирован последний элемент Вашего массива. Ваш код осуществляет сдвиг, однако последний элемент он просто дублирует.

Comment: Думаю, ваш ответ все-же больше подходит для комментария.

Comment: Вполне возможно, поскольку на данный момент не совсем разобрался между принципиальной разницей комментария и ответа.

Comment: вообще мне нужно сделать умножение двух бинарных чисел( для заполнения матрицы Голуа)  например полином 0111 умножить на образовывающий элемент 11 результат будет таким 0111 ^ 1110 = 1001 (сума по модулю 2 ) следующая строка 1001 умножить на 11 и тд. Если получается переполнение(т.е. 1хххх ) мы этот массив складываем (сума по модулю 2) с полиномом 5 разрядным (1хххх) и продолжаем дальше умножать на 11. П.С любые совпадение случайны. в моем случае масив 8 разрядный, полином 9 разрядный.

Comment: для удобства расчета я использовал полином и матрицу которую нужно умножать взял 9 разрядные, и складывал с полиномом когда в старшем разряде массива оказывалась единица.